# Locating Clojure Browser Dom

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am using the following namespace for a graphics demo

```
(ns foo.core
(:use [clojure.browser.dom :only [get-element]]))
```

However, I return a File not found exception for clojure browser dom in the classpath.
Clojurescript has been pulled, and is contained within the file I `cd` into. But is not contained in the file I am trying to load, after having accessed the REPL.

Is `clojure.browser.dom` out of date? Or, am I missing something within the implementation?

**Edit** 
I have not included the dependency for this file.

Comment: Shouldn't the library be added also to defproject :dependencies?

Comment: @pawelzieba that's most likely the issue, however I couldn't find the dependency...

Comment: I think in project.clj you need to add [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2202"] to dependencies.

Comment: @pawelzieba that dependency was already in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That namespace is correct:
https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/cljs/clojure/browser/dom.cljs

Maybe the problem is the *ns* form? Try

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require [clojure.browser.dom :refer [get-element]]))
```

Also, just in case, be sure to name your file .cljs and restart the cljsbuild compiler, just in case.